# Save video to camera roll without copying

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I am using AVCaptureSession to record video on my iPad app and I use UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(*:*:*:*:) to save it to the camera roll. The issue I am having is UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum makes a COPY of the video, which is fine unless your device is full on storage then it fails to move the video file. Is there a way to do a CUT instead of a COPY so you don't need 2x video file size in free space?